# How to hide a sidebar from a login page in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, mern

I'm trying to hide a sidebar component from showing when a user visits the signup or login page. In react-router-dom version 5, we could use a div tag inside the Switch but it has been replaced with the Route element and it throws an error when a div tag is used inside the Route element.

I'm totally a beginner who's trying to create a simple mern stack application.

```
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/home/Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import UserList from './pages/userList/UserList';
import SignUp from "./components/sign-up.component";
import Login from "./components/login.component";
import Notfound from './components/Notfound/Notfound';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
      <Sidebar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/users" element={<UserList/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/signup" element={<SignUp/>}></Route>
          <Route element={<Notfound/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: You have to create private router component for all auth routes and add your navbar component into private route component.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want to render the `Sidebar` component on select routes then the pattern in RRDv6 is you create a layout wrapper that renders the `Sidebar` and an `Outlet` component for the nested `Route` components.

[Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will
> render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const SidebarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Sidebar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

Render the routes you want to have the `Sidebar` as nested children routes.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<SidebarLayout/>}>
            <Route index element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path="/users" element={<UserList/>} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Notfound/>} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add sidebar to all the route's where you need sidebar, and inside sidebar component, you can insert other components, for example ~

```
<Route path='/' element={ 
      <div>
        <Sidebar>
          <Header/>
          <Home />
        </Sidebar>
      </div> }
 />
```

hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the  component on the /login and /signup routes, you can use the useLocation hook from react-router-dom and conditionally render the  component based on the route.

Here's the updated code to achieve that:

```js
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/home/Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import UserList from './pages/userList/UserList';
import SignUp from "./components/sign-up.component";
import Login from "./components/login.component";
import Notfound from './components/Notfound/Notfound';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  // Function to check if the current location matches certain paths
  const shouldShowSidebar = () => {
    const { pathname } = location;
    return !['/login', '/signup'].includes(pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        {shouldShowSidebar() && <Sidebar />}
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/users" element={<UserList/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/signup" element={<SignUp/>}></Route>
          <Route element={<Notfound/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this code, the useLocation hook is used to get the current location. The shouldShowSidebar function checks whether the current pathname matches the /login or /signup routes. If it does, it returns false, and the  component won't be rendered. Otherwise, it returns true, and the  component will be rendered for all other routes.